# How to get saved sidebar widget info if I know it's name in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

To get my WordPress widgets I ahve in my sidebar I am using this:

```
$sidebar_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
//print_r($sidebar_widgets);
print_r($sidebar_widgets['sidebar']);
```

and the output is like this:

```
Array ( [0] => transposh-2 [1] => nav_menu-2 [2] => text-3 [3] => monarchwidget-2 [4] => bloomwidget-2 [5] => text-5 [6] => text-4 )
```

So, I can get the name of the sidebar widget like $sidebar_widgets['sidebar'][1] - if I want the nav menu widget.

Now, the problem is how to get the title and text of this nav_menu-2 widget.

`get_option('nav_menu-2');` is not working.